# Add DividerItemDecoration effect in the begining of RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have a layout that consists of a TextView with a helper text on the top of the layout followed by a RecyclerView with the related items.

I added a DividerItemDecoration to the RecyclerView, but it only divides (I know, that's its name) the elements, but not the helper TextView from the first element of the RecyclerView.

Is there a way to extend the DividerItemDecoration in any way or I need to place an empty View element with background between the TextView and RecyclerView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want using the build-in `DividerItemDecoration` class.

The divider is drawn in a two-step process. First, `getItemOffsets()` is used to add space to the bottom of each item in the `RecyclerView`. Then, `onDraw()` is used to draw the divider within that space.

A look at the source code:

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
        RecyclerView.State state) {
    ...
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
    }
}
```

Here you can see that space is only added to the *bottom* (or right, in horizontal mode) of each item. There's no special case for the first item to give it a top offset as well.

```
private void drawVertical(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent) {
    ...
    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        parent.getDecoratedBoundsWithMargins(child, mBounds);
        final int bottom = mBounds.bottom + Math.round(child.getTranslationY());
        final int top = bottom - mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(canvas);
    }
    ...
}
```

Here you can see that the vertical boundaries for the `mDivider` drawable are computed based on bottom edge of each child view.

You could, of course, create your own implementation of `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`, and create a special case for the first item in the list.

**Edit**: Here's a stripped-down and simplified `ItemDecoration` that is based on `DividerItemDecoration` but also draws a divider on top of the first item: https://gist.github.com/zizibaloob/0c6be3e1318257950507e9c614c8aa70

Answer (score 3):

You can use View in your xml to divide recyclerView and TextView as below :

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```