# Recyclerview item increase height when fetch data again Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have recyerlView. I loaded data from the server. When it initially loads it height is normal, but when I go to the next activity through item click. And come back it slowly increasing the height of the child. I tried to debug this and found that **onResume** api call causing the issue. But What I am doing wrong in layout I don't get it.

**FirstLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**FirstActivity.kt**

```
class FirstActivity : BaseActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: FirstLayoutActivityLayoutBinding
    private val viewModel: FirstViewModel by inject()
    private var listAdapter: ListAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setupViewModel()
        binding = FirstLayoutActivityLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    private fun setupViewModel() {
        viewModel.livedata.observe(this, { list ->
            setupAdapter(list)
        })
    }

    private fun setupAdapter(list: List<String>) {
        initializeAdapter(list)
        listAdapter?.updateItemsList(list)
        binding.recyclerView.apply {
            addItemDecoration(HeaderItemDecoration(context))
             val itemDecorator = DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
        itemDecorator.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.divider)!!)
        addItemDecoration(itemDecorator)
            adapter = listAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun initializeAdapter(list: List<String>) {
        listAdapter = ListAdapter(list.toMutableList())
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        viewModel.fetchItem() // noraml retrofit call
    }
}
```

HeaderItemDecoration is used from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69409380/11560810).

**ListAdapter.kt**

```
class ListAdapter(private val list: MutableList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            ListLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItem(list[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(private val binding: ListLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bindItem(s: String) {
            binding.cool.text = s
        }
    }
}
```

**ListLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cool"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am adding my view to my [Youtube Link](https://youtu.be/2DEy8AlAsYU). Please look at what the issue is. Thanks

I didn't add any logic to increase the height

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a problem with multiple `ItemDecoration`s, which are set every time new data is fetched. to be exact: multiple `DividerItemDecoration`s, which adds small padding to the items (for dividing them). note methods name starts with `add...`, so every time you are adding new, old stays there and every instance of this divider is adding some padding. if you would implement e.g. pull-to-refresh or auto-refresh in background every e.g. 10 secs then every refresh GUI method call (`setupAdapter`) would add some space without leaving `Activity`. currently you are fetching data only once, in `onResume`, so every move-activity-to-foreground action will add one divider (when data will be fetched properly)

move this part of code to `onCreate` for setting dividers only once, thats proper place for some additional styling by code

```
binding.recyclerView.apply {
        addItemDecoration(HeaderItemDecoration(context))
        val itemDecorator = DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
        itemDecorator.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.divider)!!)
        addItemDecoration(itemDecorator)
}
```

and inside your `setupAdapter` method set only adapter to `RecyclerView`, don't style it (multiple times)

```
private fun setupAdapter(list: List<String>) {
    initializeAdapter(list)
    listAdapter?.updateItemsList(list)
    binding.recyclerView.adapter = listAdapter
}
```

Comment: great answer. Thanks a million